# How to allow user to input amount of Ether to be sent to ansmart contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs

I want a user to be able to input the amount of Ether to be sent.

```
contract SendEther{

mapping(address => uint) balanceOf;

function send(uint256 _transfer) public payable {

_transfer = msg value;
balanceOf[msg.sender] += _transfer;

}
}
```

The contract compiles in Remix but the number of Ether input, say 5, doesn't send to the contract address.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not sending the sent value out of the contract, any value sent to the contract stays there. So if you send a transaction to the function and include some Ether value along the transaction, it stays in the contract. I just don't think Remix has any native way of showing you the value.

To be sure, you could add a new function, something like this:

```
function showBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
    return address(this).balance;
}
```

Comment: I have this function in the full code.

Answer (score 0):

it's `msg.value not msg value`,
are you trying to collect ether from the user and send it to the contract, there are three ways you can do this

1. call
2. transfer
3. send

this should be the correct function

```
function send(uint256 _transfer) public payable {
  /**here you are only updating a state variable, you are not sending
   ether to the contract **/      
  balanceOf[msg.sender] += _transfer;
  //sending ether to the contract
  (bool success, bytes memory data) = address(this).call{value: msg.value)("")
}
```

specification of ether to send can only be done through msg.value, and this can be done through the frontend using ethers.js or web3.js, sending ether to the function, remix, e.t.c